# Average of numbers in a list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to import a txt file into python that contains a list of numbers.
I'm suppose to get the average of the numbers and the standard deviation of the numbers in the file. 
My script is wrong though, can someone show me the right way.

```
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv
txt = open(filename)
for line in txt:
    total = 0
    length = 0
    amount = float(line)
    total += amount
    length = length + 1
average = total/length
print average
```

Comment: And for the next time: "My script is wrong though" is not a valid error description.

Answer (score 8):

```
total = 0
length = 0
```

should be outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Move the below statements outside your loop: -

```
total = 0
length = 0
```